# How to attach "field existed in json payload" boolean metadata during deserialization of json?

Tags: java, json

I have a json body that has n number of optional fields that may or may not be present. I have a java model class which the json payload is deserialized to using jackson json. I would like the ability to attach metadata to each of the java model class member variables which stores whether or not the json field was present in the json payload.

For example my json could look like this

```
{
    "requiredFieldA": "fieldA",
    "optionalFieldC": "fieldC",
    "optionalFieldD": [{ "ObjectName" }]
}
```

Java class model looks like this

```
public class MyModel {
    string requiredFieldA;  <- metadata didExistInJson == true
    string requiredFieldB;  <- metadata didExistInJson == false
    string optionalFieldC;  <- metadata didExistInJson == true
    ArrayList<SecondModel> optionalFieldD; <- metadata didExistInJson == true
}
```

The scenario / use case I'm trying to handle is our models have null fields which get set to null if the json field is not present. But I have to reconcile fields stored in a database vs fields deserialized from the json payload. If the json payload field does not exist I must keep the database field. If it does exist then I must take the default or replace the database field value. This metadata on the deserialized object would help me achieve this design.

Curious if a solution exists in jackson json or any tips on how I can implement this.